# SpiderMonkey 1.8.5 JS::CallArgsFromVp

Tags: javascript

Всем привет! При обработке нативных вызовов с помощью SpiderMonkey 1.8.5 в документации нашел такой пример:

```
static bool
 Func(JSContext* cx, unsigned argc, JS::Value* vp)
 {
    JS::CallArgs args = JS::CallArgsFromVp(argc, vp);
 }
```

но это пример из более поздней версии SpiderMonkey 17. В SP 1.8.5 есть `CallArgs`, но нет `CallArgsFromVp`, т.е не понятно как перевести `JS::Value*` в `JS::CallArgs`.

Есть какой-нибудь аналог `CallArgsFromVp` в SP 1.8.5?

Answer (score 0):

В SP 1.8.5 для тех же целей надо использовать макросы `JS_CALLEE`, `JS_THIS` и т.д.

Т.о. в моем случае это должно выглядеть так:

```
static bool
 Func(JSContext* cx, unsigned argc, jsval *vp)
 {
    JSObject *obj = JS_THIS_OBJECT(cx, vp);
 }
```

Кто молодец? Я молодец!